# Shopify java wrapper connection, get data and post

Tags: java, shopify, shopify-app

I want to add products from a local Mysql DB to my shopify store
I have basic java programming knowledge.

I am trying to implement 
https://github.com/SevenSpikes/shopify-api-java-wrapper

I'm not sure if the API still works

Any idea on where to start?

Comment: You might want to start by testing it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [ShopifyApiClient](https://github.com/SevenSpikes/shopify-api-java-wrapper/blob/master/src/main/java/com/storakle/shopify/ShopifyApiClient.java) source code, I can only see GET requests for the majority of the Shopify functions meaning that you application can request this information and not upload it. Reading the Shopify [documentation](https://help.shopify.com/manual/products/import-export/import-products), it would seem that the preferred method is to do a CSV upload of the products.

But if you wanted to start, then try the following...

```
String accessToken = "...";
String myShopifyUrl = "...";
String nodeAddress = "...";

ShopifyApiClient client = ShopifyApiFactory.create(accessToken, myShopifyUrl, nodeAddress);
client.getProductsCount();
```

Comment: can not find method getProductCount().

Comment: I dont think any of the methods have been implemented
Do you know of any other api wrapper that works?

Comment: You are quite correct, the method is actually getProductsCount().  Have a look an alternative at the Shopify4J project and this an example of its usage  https://github.com/csaunders/Shopify4J/blob/master/ShopifyAPITests/src/com/shopify/api/endpoints/ProductsAPIEndpointTest.java